# PostCSS does not process tailwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

This is using Laravel with Vite. I have gone through guides on how to do this from multiple sources, and while there seems to be several different approaches that should work, nothing seems to result in tailwind directives being processed by postcss.

In package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "amqplib": "^0.10.0"
    }
}
```

In vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [ 
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
        
    ],
    
});
```

In postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

In tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In resources/css/app.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and finally in app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title> ISAD </title>
        @vite('resources/css/app.css')

</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Which renders as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title> ISAD </title>
        <script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

With app.css still containing just

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

There is probably something very small that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely because your vite server is being blocked by an adblocker...

Verify by opening the network tab, does the vite server and assets return an `err_blocked_by_client`?

You more than likely have to whitelist your vite server with your adblocker... You can read more on this issue here: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/47

Comment: I am using Brave browser and this is solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to re-run Vite if it's running

- `Ctrl+C` to terminate
- `npm run dev` or `yarn dev`